# How to run additional task at the end of gradle bootRun

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, bootrun

I have server application that I run using *gradle bootRun*.

I also have script *runUpdate.sh* that I need to run from command line of terminal after application is started.

I created gradle task that run this script:

```
task runUpdate(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './runUpdate.sh'
}
```

Now I want to run this script from bootRun automatically. With no need to execute additional step manually. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this the command shouldRunAfter to define that my task run before the bootRun

```
task runUpdate(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './runUpdate.sh'
}

// This will set te bootRun to wait your task run first
bootRun.configure {
    shouldRunAfter runUpdate
}
```

Answer (score -3):

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

you can use gradle dependsOn
here is a sample code

```
bootRun{
  dependsOn runUpdate
}
task runUpdate(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './runUpdate.sh'
}
```

Comment: In this case runUpdate will run first. Right? I need it will run when server is up. Can I put dependsOn bootRun into runUpdate?

Comment: Yes, `runUpdate` will run first. @Jacob, what you need is `finalizedBy`.